# Can hard drives be run on their side?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does vertical position affect hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/50413/does-vertical-position-affect-hard-drive)

Is it safe to run a hard drive on its side? I've got my upright tower case lying on its side right now (maintenance purposes), and the hard drive is running on its side with it. I've heard that you can't really run a HD in any other position other than completely horizontal but I'm not sure. Can anyone confirm that?