# Is it better to have a hard drive horizontally or vertically?

Tags: hard-drive, orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does vertical position affect hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/50413/does-vertical-position-affect-hard-drive)

This may be a silly question, but I have an external HDD which has a platform to keep it vertically.

My question is, does it make any problem to have it like that? Regarding the internal operation of the it I mean.

Comment: Hard drive feng shui ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both alignments are "standard", i.e. hard drives are constructed to work fine either way.

Personal Opinion: I haven't had problems with a number of "unusual" alignments either; I believe the only important thing is to keep the drive cool and stationary while in operation.

Comment: You're right, "cool and stationary" are the important things here. There are exceptions on the movement side - laptops can be carefully carried while running for example - but if you follow these rules you should have a long and productive relationship with your hard drive.