# Recommendation for a 500 Gb external HDD for a lot of carrying

Tags: external-hard-drive

So far I've been pretty happy with my WD Passport. But that one has spend most of its time sitting in a drawer.

I need something that will be carried around a lot (in a backpack with a notebook). Can anyone reccomend a model ?

Comment: Shopping related is off-topic.

Comment: @random - I don't know how to put this in a better way to get some opinions what should one beware of when seeking a hdd which will take some rides ...

Comment: Sounds like your question is highly related to HDD position: http://superuser.com/questions/50413/vertical-position - But you'd probably want to ask about if constant shuffling around will affect the lifespan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the WD Passport 500 for just that purpose. I gets a fair share of bouncing and I've had no problems with it.

I even run ubuntu from one of the partitions - on trains and planes it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a seagate 2TB expansion drive but I can't recommend it yet, and would actively recommend AGAINST it for the time being, as mine, after being left on all night, gave a rather worrying *CLICK* and caused the computer to pause every few seconds when I was running a DIR /S n a command window. It's a desktop model, so it requires an external power supply.

I also have a Western Digital (320GB) which I am pleased with - it's a 2.5" drive and powered from one USB socket.

I also have a HP SimplySave drive (320GB I think) which is also working well. That too is a 2.5" drive, and powered from 1 USB socket.