# Does mounting a harddisk vertically decrease its lifespan?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does vertical position affect hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/50413/does-vertical-position-affect-hard-drive)

Does mounting a harddisk harddrive vertically decrease its lifespan?

I am already aware, or guess, that:

- There is a large variety of anecdotal evidence on various forums
- Some computer manufacturers mount HDs vertically.
- Mounting a harddisk upside down may be bad (hearsay: heat issues)
- Mounting a harddisk diagonally does... whatever, I can't imagine anyone doing that
- Rotating harddisk while it is in operation may cause strain due to torque

I am merely interested in whether a harddisk mounted vertically will last any shorter than if it was horizontally mounted. **Has there been any scientific study?** =)

Please note that there are 3 ways to vertically-mount a harddisk drive:

---

### "sideways"

[image]

---

### "controller-up"

(upside-down I will call "controller-down")

[image]