# Are there any issues storing laptops vertically?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have one shelf with four racks and five laptops. Storing them horizontally would waste a lot of space. So I want to store them vertically.

I have seen laptops being stored vertically at second-hand laptop stores. Does storing laptops vertically pose any risks with their hardware, particularly the hard-disk drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does vertical position affect the lifespan or integrity of a hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/50413/does-vertical-position-affect-the-lifespan-or-integrity-of-a-hard-drive)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion there is no issue(s) with laptop's being stored vertically because they are built compactly. Hence, no matter how you position your laptop in a shelf will post no threat at all as long as it doesn't fall.

PS : I am assuming it is completely power off before you store it.

Answer (score -1):

This is all relative speculation from my experience with technology, but here goes;

Overall, no, there shouldn't be a problem with this. These components are not moving if the device is powered off, so there's little threat to something breaking or moving out of place. Laptops nowadays are also starting to come with solid state drives or m.2 Sata drives, further removing movable parts.

Answer (score -1):

No problem at all especially if the laptop has a solid state drive.  The only foreseeable issue relating to vertical storage would be the mechanical hard drive over time.  I can say that Toshiba recommend their units stored flat, but this probably doesn't apply as of 2017.